# NOt able to read a InputStream

Tags: android

```
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line ="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){

                result += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;
```

message shows nothing, result is not given

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are not appending the line into your result.
Make result variable String Buffer and use append function to do so then return the string from string buffer using toString function